# How to fix Nameerror: name 'enemy' is not defined...?

Tags: python, function, parameters, nameerror

```
import random
from itertools import zip_longest
from SpeciesList import fighters_list

class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, age: int, health: int, happiness: int) -> None:
        self.age = 0
        self.total_health = 0
        self.current_health = 0
        self.happiness = 0

    def get_age(self):
        self.age = random.randint(8, 100)
    
    def get_total_health(self):
        self.total_health = random.randint(100, 250)
     
    def get_happiness(self):
        self.happiness = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(f"{self.happiness}% happy")



#--------FIGHTERS--------

#----FIGHTER CLASS----
class Fighter(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, species, level):
        self.name = name
        self.species = species
        self.level = level
        self.ferocity = 0
        self.toughness = 0
        self.attack_damage = 0.0
        self.total_health = 0
        self.current_health = self.total_health
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def fighter_age(self):
       self.get_age()
       self.age = self.age / 2
       print(f"{int(round(self.age))} years old ")
       
    def update_health(self):
        self.total_health += self.level
    
    def get_ferocity(self):
        self.ferocity = random.randint(1,100)
        print(f"{self.ferocity}% ferocious")

    def get_level(self):
        self.level = min(random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100))
        print(f"lvl {self.level}")
        
    def get_toughness(self):
        self.toughness = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(f"{self.toughness}% toughness")

    def get_species(self):
        species_choice = random.randint(0, len(fighters_list)-1)
        self.species = fighters_list[species_choice]
        print(self.species)
        
    def do_attack(self):
        self.attack_damage = random.randint(10, 100)
        print(self.attack_damage)


    def be_attacked(self, enemy_attack_damage):
        self.current_health -= enemy_attack_damage
        if self.current_health > 0:
            print(f"{self.current_health}/{self.total_health} health")
        elif self.current_health <= 0:
            print("Dead")
    

    def create_stats(self):
        print(f"---{self.name}---")
        print(self.species)
        print(f"lvl {self.level}")
        self.fighter_age()
        self.get_total_health()
        self.current_health = self.total_health
        print(f"{self.total_health}/{self.total_health} health")
        self.get_happiness()
        self.get_ferocity()
        self.get_toughness()
         
    def check_stats(self):
        print("")
        print(f"---{self.name}---")
        print(f"{self.species}")
        print(f"lvl {self.level}")
        print(f"{int(self.age)} years old")
        print(f"{self.current_health}/{self.total_health} health")
        print(f"{self.happiness}% happy")
        print(f"{self.ferocity}% ferocious")
        print(f"{self.toughness}% toughness")

    def level_up(self):
        self.level += 1
        self.update_health()

#----ENEMY FIGHTER CLASS----

class Enemy_Fighter(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        self.species = ''
        self.level = 0
        self.attack_damage = 0.0
        self.total_health = 0
        self.current_health = self.total_health

    def get_species(self):
        species_choice = random.randint(0, len(fighters_list)-1)
        self.species = fighters_list[species_choice]
        print(self.species)

    def get_level(self):
        self.level = min(random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 100))
        print(f"lvl {self.level}")

    def create_stats(self):
        self.get_species()
        self.get_level()
        self.get_total_health()
        self.current_health = self.total_health
        print(f"{self.total_health}/{self.total_health} health")

    def get_attack(self):
        self.attack_damage = random.randint(10, 100)
        print(self.attack_damage)

    def be_attacked(self, enemy_attack_damage):
        self.current_health -= enemy_attack_damage
        if self.current_health > 0:
            print(f"{self.current_health}/{self.total_health} health")
        elif self.current_health <= 0:
            print("Dead")

#----FIGHTER CREATION/REPLACEMENT----
def create_fighter(name: str) -> Fighter:
    creature = Fighter(name, enemy.species, enemy.level)
    creature.create_stats()
    print(" \n \n \n")
    return creature

def replace_fighter(new_name, replaced: str) -> Fighter:

    fighters.pop(replaced)
    fighters[new_name] = create_fighter(new_name)



fighters = {}

#----FIGHTER COMMANDS----
def create_fighter_name():
    name = input("What will you call your fighter?\n> ")
    fighters[name] = create_fighter(name)

def fighter_line_up():
    print("Your fighter line-up")
    for i, creature in zip_longest(range(6), fighters):
        print(f"{i + 1}: {creature}")

def check_fighter():
    check_creature = input(" \nWhich fighter would you like to check? (name)\n> ")
    fighters[check_creature].check_stats()


def find_fighter():
    if (population := len(fighters)) < 6:
        create_fighter_name()
    
    elif population >= 6:
        print(" \nYour fighter line-up is full!\nPlease choose a fighter to replace! (name)")
        print("If you do not want to replace a fighter, type 'No'!")
        fighter_line_up()
        replacing = True
        while replacing:
            replace_f = input("> ")
            if replace_f.upper() == 'NO':
                break
            else:
                confirmation = input("Are you sure?\n> ")
                if confirmation.upper() == 'YES':
                    new_fighter_name = input(" \nWhat will be your fighters name?\n> ")
                    replace_fighter(new_fighter_name, replace_f)
                    break
                if confirmation.upper() == 'NO':
                    print("Who will you replace?")


def explore():
    print("You went exploring...")
    chance_of_encounter = random.randint(1, 100)
    if chance_of_encounter <= 75:
        do_encounter()
        confirmation = input(" \nDo you want to attempt to catch it?\n> ")
        if confirmation.upper() == 'YES':
                chance_of_catch = random.randint(1, 100)
                if chance_of_catch <= 75:
                    print("You caught the wild animal!")
                    find_fighter()
                else:
                    print("You lost the animal!")


def do_encounter():
    type_of_creature_chance = random.randint(1, 3)
    if type_of_creature_chance == 1 or 2 or 3:
        print("You were ambushed by a creature!")
        enemy = Enemy_Fighter()
        enemy.create_stats()
    return enemy.species, enemy.level








active = True
while active:
    action = input(" \nWhat do you want to do?\n EXPLORE   CHECK TEAM\n QUIT\n> ")
    if action.upper() == 'EXPLORE':
        explore()
    elif action.upper() == 'CHECK TEAM':
        fighter_line_up()
        if len(fighters) > 0:
            action = input("Would you like to check on a fighter?\n> ")
        else:
            print("Your fighter line-up is empty!")
        if action.upper() == 'YES':
            try:
                check_fighter()
            except KeyError:
                print("This name is not recognised. Please try again.")
```

I believe the problem resides in the 'do_encounter():' function and the create_fighter(name: str) function however i cant discover how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

I have also tried creating fixed variables with the species and level of the enemy within the 'do_encounter():' function, yet it wields the same result of nameError: name 'species' is not defined.

A copy of the traceback error was asked, so i have added it here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\~Coding Stuff\Python Code\Pokemon game\Pokemon-esque Game.py", line 231, in <module>
    explore()
  File "D:\~Coding Stuff\Python Code\Pokemon game\Pokemon-esque Game.py", line 207, in explore
    find_fighter()
  File "D:\~Coding Stuff\Python Code\Pokemon game\Pokemon-esque Game.py", line 176, in find_fighter
    create_fighter_name()
  File "D:\~Coding Stuff\Python Code\Pokemon game\Pokemon-esque Game.py", line 162, in create_fighter_name
    fighters[name] = create_fighter(name)
  File "D:\~Coding Stuff\Python Code\Pokemon game\Pokemon-esque Game.py", line 145, in create_fighter
    creature = Fighter(name, enemy.species, enemy.level)
NameError: name 'enemy' is not defined
```

Comment: This error shouldn't happen in `do_encounter` since you did another mistake (bad `if` condition) that prevents it. Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: This is far more code than you need to reproduce the problem. Provide a [mcve] instead.

Comment: I added the full error traceback

Comment: Well, you _didn't_ define `enemy` in the `create_fighter` function.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In `create_fighter` you use `enemy` without defining it.

In `do_encounter` you return fields from `enemy` whether or not the if statement that binds it is run.

edit:

the `do_encounter` thing isn't causing your current error due to a different error you have made.

`type_of_creature_chance == 1 or 2 or 3`

this doesn't mean what you think it means.

this means if type_of_creature == 1 is true OR if the number 2 is considered true ( all numbers but 0 are ) OR if the number 3 is considered true ( all numbers but 0 are )

It will always run as written.

I'm sure you meant `type_of_creature_chance in [1, 2, 3]`

That will cause my warning about using fields from enemy when not defined to ring true, so you'll need to decide what to do if enemy isn't one of those values and correct the function.

Comment: Im not sure if im understanding wrong, but is enemy not defined in the 'Do_encounter' function?

Comment: `enemy = Enemy_Fighter()` is inside an if statement. as I said, you're accidentally always triggering it right now. `enemy` is used after and outside the `if` statement too. if the if statement isn't true ( enemy isn't type 1/2/3 ), then it will still do the `return enemy.species, enemy.level`, which would error because you used `enemy` without defining it ( having skipped the if statement ).

the big error is in `create_fighter` where you have a line that says `creature = Fighter(name, enemy.species, enemy.level)`, but don't have any `enemy` defined or accepted as a parameter.

Comment: I fixed it by removing the If statement and setting the two variables from enemy as global variables called 'e_spec' and 'e_lev', this works but im not sure its the most efficient way around doing it. Thanks for helping. :)